# ERROR 1064 (42000):ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

I created a new user but had trouble granting access. But I'm able to log into mysql with the new user 'apple.2' but I can't grant it access or create a database. I have another user called 'apple' but I don't think that's the problem.

```
~$ mysql -u apple.2 -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 215
Server version: 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> create database apple.2_class;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.2_class' at line 1

mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'apple.2' identified by 'password';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'apple.2'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0):

databases don't have `.` in their names unless quoted.

```
create database `apple.2_class`;
```

Database names are different from user names. You need to use a higher priv user, usually `root`, to grant the privs to `apple.2`

Get into the practice of creating a user, then giving it grants. The combined version of this has gone away in MySQL-8.0.

```
create user 'apple.2' identified by 'password';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'apple.2';
```

Comment: so would i have to create the user in root? if so how?

Comment: ` mysql -u root -p`

Comment: I get an error
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)